# Vuetify tooltip is wrong position when in footer section

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Can't resolve problem with vuetify tooltip. In the code below, after page scroll, tooltip moves upper.
Even `fixed="true"` not helps.

The code:

```
<v-footer app inset fixed>
  <v-row align="center">
    <v-col class="shrink px-1">
      <v-tooltip top>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn
            icon
            outlined
            v-on="on"
            @click="dryRun"
          >
            <v-icon>flash_on</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <span>Tooltip</span>
      </v-tooltip>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-footer>
```

https://codepen.io/vitalypdev/pen/QWLmBLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use attach on the tooltip to change the DOM element who the tooltip is attached to, default is the v-app element

```
<v-tooltip top attach>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn
          icon
          outlined
          v-on="on"
          @click="dryRun"
        >
            <v-icon>flash_on</v-icon>
       </v-btn>
   </template>
   <span>Tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Comment: For some reason this solution is not works, tooltip still appears in wrong position after page scroll, you can verify it at codepen..

Comment: Oh sorry, i thought the problem was the tooltip scrolling with the page and using attach if you scroll the page while the tooltip is open it remains fixed but you're right, it's still not working. Read [thjis](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/8887), apparently they lost --fixed attribute in some update but they are bringing it back

Comment: Got it! This bug was fixed in v.2.0.16, as you pointed to. I just updated my vuetify from 2.0.5 to 2.0.16, and it fix my problem, without any additional coding. Thanks!

Comment: How can we do the same thing with "position: sticky"?